# When can we stop assuming that a 2 digit year starts with 19

Tags: forms, validation, dates

If the user inputs only 2 digits, should I assume that they mean 19XX?

I have inline validation that validates a given range (eg 1900 - 2014), but if they type in 13, does it mean 2013 or 1913.

Some of the fields will be birthdays of family members, so it could be anything.

I want to avoid using text because we'll have to translate it.

Comment: Simple solution: force a 4-digit year.

Comment: Suggested alt. Question:  When can we assume that a 2 digit year means 20XX?

Comment: You could always detect when the user has typed a two digit number that is not 19 or 20, and throw up a dialogue asking 'Which Century?'. Seriously though, I agree with @EvilClosetMonkey, a 4 digit year is simplest option

Comment: @EvilClosetMonkey, how would you would force 4-digit year with keeping the validation on the client side and without using text?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "not using text". '2014' is easily validated as a number with Javascript. Perhaps you can post an example of your current solution? Also - you should always do server side validation, even if you do client side validation (sometimes the client doesn't validate, for any number of reasons).

Comment: @EvilClosetMonkey How do you tell them that "09" is wrong without using any words? I don't think just making it red would be enough to tell them that they need to add "20" or "19".  Yes I validate on the server side.

Comment: You are correct that just adding a red border (for example) would not be enough. Errors need words. If you are wanting to make sure the user enters a 4-digit year you will need an error that displays text of some sort. Well formatted errors are an important part of UX and words are an important part of well formatted errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would feel relatively safe in assuming that any 2 digits that are equal to or less than the last 2 digits of the current year are describing the current year. So today, it would be numbers 00-14. There is a small chance that there are people 100+ years old that will be excluded but in today's world, when I say "back in '07" I mean 2007 and not 1907 so those people will most likely input the full year.

That said, this ambiguity should be solved another way if possible. Make it clear that the entire year should be entered. If you must "auto-complete," the 4-digit year should show up immediately as a soft confirmation that you understood which of the centuries they meant.

Comment: I ended up doing it @user47924's way, if somebody puts in 07, it appends 20, if somebody puts in 84, it appends 19. But you can still type in 1907 or 2084 if needed.